# Have src attributes use same protocol as page

Tags: javascript, html, ssl, https, src

I have a site that uses **https** in some places, and **http** in others.

Wasn't a problem until I realized that my scripts with relative paths would always use http. Is it possible to have my relative path `src` attributes use whichever protocol is used for the page?

Originally I was thinking I could just use `location.protocol` and `location.host`, but then realized I'm not actual in javascript when setting the src attributes!

Any ideas?

```
<script src="/foobar"></script>
```

Comment: How do the tags “javascript” and “ssl” relate to the question?

Comment: When a relative URL is resolved, the protocol part of the base URL is used, so the observation that `http` is always used must be incorrect. Unless you have a `base` element, the protocol used for relative URLs is `https` when the page itself was retrieved with `https`. Please clarify what makes you think things are different. Are you actually referring to URLs within the script itself (content of the script file) and not the `script` element’s `src` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relative paths will take the protocol and host that the page uses. If this needs to change you could use the [BASE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag.

Also when using absolute paths a double slash will inherit the page's protocol: `src="//host.com/path"` will be https on an https page and http on an http page.